# Connection between graph spectra and graph homomorphisms

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Since there are many properties of graph which can be expressed in terms of both existence of graph homomorphisms and graph spectra I expect there are some papers exploring this connection between graph spectra and graph homomorphisms.

Any thoughts on this topic? Papers, books, people...?

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a large overlap; the basic problem is that homomorphisms generally destroy nearly all spectral information. There are important exceptions though. Thus in https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00969, David Roberson resolves a conjecture of Cameron and Kazanidis by proving that if a strongly regular graph is not a core then its core is a complete graph; by my standards at least, his proof is a spectral proof.